# Seeking Python API to assess accessibility to foodbank site?

Tags: python, software-recommendations, routing, api, spyder

The aim is to look at accessibility or lack thereof, in certain areas of the city, in order to inform future foodbank services.

I have been working in Python/Spyder, and using OpenRouteService API to calculate the routes.

However the project coordinator from the Foodbank, has recently suggested that it would be beneficial to add another layer of granularity to the project - using public transport data and timetables - as foodbank sessions run at distinct times through the week.

Can anyone recommend an appropriate API I could use in Python?

I have looked at https://developer.here.com/ which seems to be only available in other languages.

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the HERE API there's a [Python API wrapper](https://github.com/abdullahselek/HerePy) but I've not tried this.

There's a good list of other Public Transport APIs [here on GitHub](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis#transportation).

I see you're in the UK. The UK Government published a data set called [NaPTAN](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/national-public-transport-access-node-schema) which had detailed public transportation data of routes, access points, timetables etc.

However, it's been several years since I last looked at this, and I'm not sure whether this is still used/updated. I also remember looking at the schema, and realising how complex public transportation actually is ;-)

There was a Python tool called [naptanToOSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/NaPTAN/Import) used for a while to bring some of this data (bus stops etc.) into OpenStreetMap, but again I'm not sure of its status.